# Ionic 2 - Binding Values Across Tabs Pages

Tags: ionic2

I have a 12 page form, where users switch between the pages using tabs. I have  in page 4, and I want to read its value or bind it with components in page 9 and 10.

How do I do this?

Comment: you can check out https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/

Answer (score 1):

The best way around this seems to be either using Storage to persist the data, or to use a Provider and share the data around the pages.